# VirtualEnv and Python 2.7 / sqlite3 import

Tags: python, import

Ive installed python 2.7. If I go into python I can import sqlite3. However if I use a virtual environment and then try to import sqlite3 the module is not found.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you importing `sqlite` or `sqlite3`? Your post uses both names.

Comment: Install sqlite in your virtualenv or create env with [--system-site-packages](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv#the-system-site-packages-option) option.

Comment: sqlite is not found when i try to install it via pip(??)